# An English word rhyming with perfection, meaning happiness, success, enjoyment, etc

Tags: single-word-requests, rhymes

> The reason why I might have a very low self-esteem  has to be the fact that I tried all my life to go for **perfection**, so I never saw my strengths, I just looked for faults and issues to correct. Other people, on the other hand, who enjoy a great self-esteem, focused on **elevation**, thus making any strength they discovered or developed work in their favor. Ultimately, I suppose they sought happiness, while I sought perfection.

I am looking for an English word harmonious with perfection, and it should  mean something like happiness, enjoyment, achievement, pleasure, etc. It is to put it in the place of *elevation* in the paragraph.

Comment: [Satisfaction](https://youtu.be/nrIPxlFzDi0) (or exhilaration, elation, delectation, girly action, girl reaction)?

Comment: "who enjoyed greater self-esteem, focused on **escalation**," also 'effection' (obs., but would meet with ready understanding as 'the process of effecting', 'accomplishment, performance').

Comment: I have no idea why this question and the answers are so heavily down voted. Maybe you can include some of your research and words that you have excluded already.

Comment: You might be able to do something with "confection".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***delectation***

[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/delectation) identifies it as a mass noun meaning "pleasure and delight."

Comment: Hi, aparente001. I'm not the downvoter, but I did think that your original answer would be better with a link to the dictionary that the definition you cited probably came from—so I added one. In any case, citing Google as the source tends not to be very helpful.

Comment: @SvenYargs - Why?  Nowadays, typing *define delectation* into the universal whats-it box causes Google to return a nicely formatted, if simplified, dictionary entry, right at the top of the page.  I identified my source, and it is extremely easy to reproduce my results (i.e. retrace my steps).

Comment: As a matter of citation, it seems to me, Google is merely the conduit to the definition while Oxford Living Dictionaries is the definition's source. If I were to visit the library and find and quote a definition from a big dictionary in the reference room, I could give "from the library" as my source, but that doesn't really give credit where credit is due.

Comment: @SvenYargs - "The library" is clearly not enough to enable someone to retrace our steps.  Are you saying that citing a google definition is similarly unclear?

Comment: I'm saying that Google didn't write the definition and the example that appear as the top result when you search for _delectation_; Google provides the information in a nice window at the top of the first search results page, but Google isn't the institutional author of that information. Regrettably, Google doesn't cite the actual source, which I think is bad form—though Google obviously disagrees. To find that source, you have to search for "pleasure and delight" + "a box of chocolates for their delectation", which takes you [here](http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1O999-delectation.html).

Comment: @SvenYargs - Are they consistent in taking their definitions from the same source consistently?  If not, then I will not say "google" as my source any more.

Comment: That I don't know. I do recommend that you try in each case to find and credit the actual source of content that Google presents without attribution—but whether you do or don't, I promise not to bug you about it again.

Answer (score 2):

You might find that ***affection*** could fit quite nicely.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affection

" :  the feeling aspect (as in pleasure) of consciousness"

> The reason why I might have a very low self-esteem has to be the fact that I tried all my life to go for **perfection**, so I never saw my strengths, I just looked for faults and issues to correct. Other people, on the other hand, who enjoy a great self-esteem, focused on **affection**, thus making any strength they discovered or developed work in their favor. Ultimately, I suppose they sought happiness, while I sought perfection.

Answer (score 1):

Consider **[self-actualization](http://Self-actualization)**

The term was coined by Abraham Maslow back in 1954, when he wrote about the ‘hierarchy of needs’.

> [Definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-actualization): The achievement of one's full potential through
>   creativity, independence, spontaneity, and a grasp of the real world.
>   *Self-actualization* refers to the need for personal growth and development that exists throughout your life. If you are
>   self-actualized, you work hard to grow and become who you want to be
>   in life and reach your full potential.